# Define a function for a curve

Tags: graphing-functions

I am stuck with this problem longer than I'd like to admit.
I wanna define a function which looks like this:

[image: Graph]
It starts at $(0,0)$, then increases up to a maximum and then decreases, never reaching $0$.

I would like to change the rate of increase, the maximum point, and the rate of decrease.

Comment: Reminds me of the Poisson distribution ...

Comment: What's the domain of $f$? Is $f$ continuous? Is it smooth? I think you need to provide more information

Comment: @MattiP. For certain values of $\lambda$, sure. However, different values of $\lambda$ seems to me to change the shape drastically from what is in the picture.

Comment: $f(x)=Mx^\alpha e^{-\beta x}$ satisfy all your requirements for every $\alpha >0$, $\beta >0$, $M >0$

Answer (score 0):

You could start by taking two positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ and then define $f(x)=\dfrac{ax}{x^2+b}$ ($x\in\mathbb{R}^+$).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

$$f(x)=\frac{\log(x+1)}{x+1}$$

for $x\in[0,+\infty)$

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x%2B1)%2F(x%2B1)